# Mimic lambdas in plain C(msvc) - recursive lambdas

Tags: c, lambda, c-preprocessor

So I was posed the challenge of mimicking lambda definitions in plain C on the msvc compiler (it doesn't support gcc extensions) - I came up with a file inclusion solution which basically mirrors the file at the top. It works fine for most cases but what if I want to include a lambda inside my lambda:

```
#ifndef FIRSTPASS
#include <stdio.h>

//here comes your "nested" definitions
#define FIRSTPASS
#include "source.c"
#undef FIRSTPASS

main(){
#else
    int global = 2;
    int func() 
    {
        //define another "lambda" here
        printf("%d\n", global);
    }
#endif
#ifndef FIRSTPASS
    func();}
#endif
```

Comment: What characteristics of a lambda do you intend to mimic with that?  Because I don't see that you're gaining much.  In particular, you are not closing over `main()`'s local variable `global`, but rather creating two different variables with that name in different scopes, with one shadowing the other.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can use variadic arguments to pass locals if needed. Right here I'm mainly mimicking the possibility to declare a function inside another function text wise.

Comment: Well, the point of nested functions is generally to have overlapping scope, and the syntactic trick you're employing does not achieve that, so I don't see the point.  But if that floats your boat, then you should be able to use the same trick again to layer on however many more levels you like.